# Command works in SSH terminal, but not in PHP script

Tags: php, linux, ssh, ffmpeg, plesk

I'm having a weird problem. I have installed ffmpeg on my server. When I run "`ffmpeg`" from SSH (PuTTY) it confirms the install:

[image: ffmpeg via ssh]

Then I placed the following code in a PHP file, inside a website on the same server:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$output = exec('ffmpeg -h');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

However when I run the PHP script, the page is blank, there is no output. I can confirm that `exec` is working fine, because when I run `php -v | grep cli` both in PHP and in terminal, they both output the same thing.

I am using Plesk (web host edition) to manage the site, and have given it access to the server over SSH (**/bin/sh**)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try finding where `ffmpeg` is located using `which ffmpeg`, and then using the full path in the `exec` line, e.g. `$output = exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -h');`

Comment: *"What am I missing here?"* -- you use different users to run the command. These users (the one you use with `ssh` and the one that runs the web server) use different startup scripts and have different values for their `$PATH` environment variables. The shell uses the paths from `$PATH` to find an executable file when it is invoked without a complete path. Use `which ffmpeg` (in your `ssh` session) to find out where is the `ffmpeg` program located and put its complete path into the PHP script.

Comment: Still, doesn't seem to work. Very weird, using: `exec('/root/bin/ffmpeg -h', $output);` (amended exec method using AbraCadaver's answer)

Comment: Read The Friendly Manual. exec returns the last line of the output -- looks blank in this case. Use the 2nd and 3rd params: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Also, consider safe_mode restrictions "Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable."

Comment: Using the 3rd param outputs "126"... `exec('/root/bin/ffmpeg -h', $output, $return);echo "<pre>$return</pre>";`

Comment: Update: I did a chmod on the file (ffmpeg). It came back with an "open_basedir restriction in effect" error. I've now fixed that by changing the PHP settings, setting open_basedir to none. Now when doing `chmod('/root/bin/ffmpeg',0777);` I get a permission denied error! The 3rd param of exec (return_var) now shows 127

Comment: retval of 126 or 127 says the command returned an error. I dunno if this would be a PHP error or an ffmpeg error. Try altering your command to route stderr to stdout **exec('ffmpeg -h 2>&1')** and then take a look at the $output ---**important** - exec only returns one line of output, you need to supply a 2nd param to collect all of it, then var_dump the result to see all the output.

Comment: Altering the command as suggested returns `array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "sh: ffmpeg: command not found" }`

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't using the full path. When using the full path `exec('/root/bin/ffmpeg -h 2>&1', $output, $return);`, it returns this: `array(1) { [0]=> string(39) "sh: /root/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied" }`... So it knows it's there, it just doesn't have permission

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the full path to `ffmeg` as it's likely not in the webserver user's path environment variable.

Also, the return of `exec()` is the last line of output, which may be a blank line, you never know.  So use the second parameter to capture all output in an array:

```
exec('/path/to/ffmpeg -h', $output);
echo implode('<br>', $output);
```

Or you can try `system()` or `passthru()` to output directly:

```
echo "<pre>" . system('/path/to/ffmpeg -h') . "</pre>";
```

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: If you view the source of the HTML page do you see the `<pre>` tags?

Comment: Use the 3rd parameter (return_val) for exec, if it returns something other than zero, there's an error. Also, consider routing stderr to stdout.

Comment: Yes, I see the <pre> tags. Also @S. Imp, see above.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/root/bin/ffmpeg -h');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

**EDIT - ADDITION**

However, the issue in this case is that files in /root are not available to the web server user for security reasons.  The ffmpeg executable should go into `/usr/local/bin` or another directory where it is available to the web server user.

Comment: Same thing here too.

Comment: What are the permission for /root/bin/ffmpeg?  Does your web server user have permission to execute it?

Comment: Permissions are 0755 on that file. I've given access for that user to access the server over SSH (/bin/sh), can't see anything else for user permissions in my Plesk panel.

Comment: That looks correct to me and I would think that it would run.  I tested the code that I provided on my server and it works on my server, I get output.  Your getting a blank page? Is it even outputting the <pre> tags?  Is your webserver properly executing PHP?

Comment: See above comments in the original question. Seems to be a permission problem.

Comment: Just saw that.  The problem might be that it is located in /root.  Can you move /root/bin/ffmpeg to something like /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg and try running it from there?

Comment: Weird, I get the same permission denied error. Is there somewhere else I can place it maybe?

Comment: I am slightly confused. I am able to use `youtube-dl` from exec in PHP, which is in the same folder as `ffmpeg`, yet I can't run ffmpeg?

Comment: Hmmmmmm, I don't think moving it somewhere else will help.  You could possibly try using chown to give ownership of ffmpeg to the web server user.  But, you shouldn't need to do that so I doubt it will make much difference. Yes, I agree ... weird.

Comment: What do you get for output when you run `/root/bin/ffmpeg -h` from the command line of your SSH Putty session?

Comment: I get the normal help output of `ffmpeg`

Comment: Managed to solve it. Your original suggestion about moving the files into that directory was correct, however when I moved the files their permissions had changed. Changing them back to 0755 worked. Thanks!